# Supporting web login for limited input devices

Tags: android, google-app-engine, servlets, google-glass

I am developing for Glass and I'm trying to send files to my GAE servlet app.  My issue is that sending requests to my running servlet forces me to sign in.  But because Glass has no means of text input, I get stuck and the authentication fails.  I saw that Google supports accessing Google APIs using Oauth 2.0 on limited input devices via a verification code and url. The details can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#device).  How would I implement this on my servlet?  Alternatively,  how I would use the input capabilities of the phone connected to Glass to sign-in on behalf of the Glass device?  Any other ideas would be very much appreciated.  Also, if I should add any reference information or code I would be happy to do so.

Comment: Using your phone for the sign in process is actually one way of implementing OAuth 2.0 on limited input devices. Read [this](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ForDevices#obtainingacode) on the response values you will need to send to your Glass device.

Comment: Revisiting this problem, you can also let the user sign in to your service at the beginning, when the user turns your Glassware on in MyGlass. After inserting the newly authenticated account in AccountManager, you can use authentication tokens to verify a user's identity when accessing your servlet.